# Instead of insert trigger SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create an 'instead of insert trigger' that will not let the name 'john' insert anything into a table.  My problem is that even if i change the name to something else, the query is successful but the values arent added.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadOfTrigger
ON Question4
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS  
Declare @name varchar(50)
Declare @question varchar(50)
Declare @Answer char
Set @name = 'John'
IF (select Username from inserted) = @name
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('You have not paid up your fee', 10,1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO question4
values (@name, @question, @Answer)
END
```

Comment: My guess would be with SQL getting mixed up with the `BEGIN` and `END` statements.
you said the query is successful. I guess you mean it does not throw an error.
try `RAISERROR` in both sides of `IF` statement and see if it throws.

Comment: You're fundamental flaw is that you seem to think the trigger will be call **once per row**. That's not the case - it's being called **once per statement**, and if your `INSERT` statement inserts more than one row, the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain **multiple rows** - and in that case - which of the multiple rows are you selecting with your `(select Username from inserted) ` statement?? You need to **rewrite your trigger** to take **multiple rows in `Inserted`** into account!

Answer (score 4):

Ok So I have removed your `BEGIN` and `END` statements between your `IF ELSE` statement and wrapped the trigger logic within a `BEGIN END`

As mentioned in the comments below you dont need the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Also you will need to populate @question and @Answer for those to be of any use.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadOfTrigger
ON Question4
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

Declare @name varchar(50)
Declare @question varchar(50)
Declare @Answer char

Set @name = 'John'

IF (select Username from inserted) = @name
    RAISERROR ('You have not paid up your fee', 10,1)
    --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
ELSE
    INSERT INTO question4
    values (@name, @question, @Answer)

END
```

Comment: ROLLBACK TRANSACTION is not needed

Comment: These answers would be better if you identified and/or explained what you have changed.

Comment: @bendataclear I mentioned in my comment on the question what I think the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I notice you have declared, but not actually set a value for your variables in your else statement this may have caused SQL to not insert what you expected.
Strangely enough I'm required to do the same in an assignment at the moment, Here's my solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER instead_of_insert
ON Question4

INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

Declare @Username varchar(25) 
Declare @Question varchar(6)
Declare @Answer char(1)

Set @Username ='John'

IF (Select UserName from inserted) = @UserName
Begin
RAISERROR ('You have not paid up your fee', 10,1)
End

Else
Begin

Set @Username = (Select UserName from inserted)
Set @Question = (Select Question_ID from inserted)
Set @Answer = (Select Answer from inserted)

Insert into User_Responses 
Values
(@username, @Question, @Answer) 

End
```